# Cannot override the error message of data attributes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

First Hee is how a simple data attribute looks like

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="843")]
```

The problem is that I need to get the error message of data annotation attribute from database (depending on the number I have - in this case 843). SO what I tried in my code is for each properties of the type   I get it's attributes.   Then for each attribute of this property I get its error message with the help of extension method. The problem is that I cannot override the errormessage property of the attribute.

```
     [HttpPost]
  public virtual ActionResult Register(Users user)
  { 
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        //code when everything ids OK
      }
      foreach (var prop in typeof(Users).GetProperties())
      {
                    object[] attrs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false);
                    if (attrs == null || attrs.Length == 0)
                        continue;  
                    foreach (var attr in attrs)
                    {
                        string errorMes = user.GetAttribute<RequiredAttribute>(prop.Name).ErrorMessage;                       
                        user.GetAttribute<RequiredAttribute>(prop.Name).ErrorMessage = repository.GetAttribute(errorMes );
                    }
     }
```

Here is my extension method which gets teh exact attribute od thw instance:

```
public static T GetAttribute<T>(this object instance, string propertyName) where T : Attribute
        {
            var attrType = typeof(T);
            var property = instance.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
            return (T)property.GetCustomAttributes(attrType, false).First();
        }
```

No matter what number I give I always have the default error message= And the strange thing is that I see very clearly that the errormessage property of attribute class can be set. 
Can you give simple clues or other methods so I can achieve my goal

Comment: Error messages are added to `ModelState` during the binding process, which occurs before any of the code in the POST method is executed

Comment: And can you suggest something - what is the best way to achieve this goal. Thank you by the way for the  response=

Comment: If your messages need to be in a database, you could manually check the validity of a property, and if not valid, look up the value and add your message the `ModelState.Errors` collection - `ModelState.AddModelError("yourPropertyName", "your error message");` Alternatively you could look at using resource files.